# Form.Show causing to loose Row selection

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I am setting the current row using the following code

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    gSelectedPlant = StaticClass.GlobalValue;

    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[gSelectedPlant].Cells[0];
    dataGridView1.Rows[gSelectedPlant].Selected = true;
    gSelectedPlant = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
}
```

In my second form which has a back button.

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int plantid = StaticClass.GlobalValue;
    //Properties.Settings.Default.PlantId = plantid;

    Program.fPlant = new frmPlant(plantid);
    Program.fPlant.Show();
    this.Hide();

 }
```

Now the databindind in the first form works well . but at Program.fPlant.Show(), rowselection reverts to the default(first row), but I need it maintain selected row

Comment: What you have shown works fine - the problem lies on some code you haven't shown, possibly the constructor or the frmPlant or in your Program class - also, is `Program.fPlant` a static reference to a class? Show all you code please.

Comment: Also as an aside - the way you approach this, which seems to be with lots of global variables is probably a bad design.