# How a DataGridView keeps the position of a selected row after event population in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How a DataGridView keeps the position of a selected row after event population in VB.NET.

I want without using bindingsource whether it can be applied please guide.

For database information, the table does not have an ID but has a primarykey of 4 columns, namely:CODEPRODUCT,BARCODE,COLORCODE,SIZE

Thanks

```
 Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
  Dim dataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
  Dim GetConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\demo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private Sub population()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * from stocks"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        'Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        Me.DataGridView1.MultiSelect = False
        population()
    End Sub
  Private Sub Btnrefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnrefresh.Click
        population()
    End Sub
```

result in datagridview 19082023

[image: result in datagridview 19082023]

Comment: If you reload the same data (not clear why), you can simply store the `CurrentCell` index, otherwise you have to store a value that represents the `ID` of the actual data, then find it -- You have more than one thing to fix in that code

Comment: @Jimi , thanks your reply, this is only a sample so if I update then I have to call the "population" method and in the actual data it does not have an "ID" but for the 4 columns it is primarykey (CODEPRODUCT,BARCODE,COLORCODE,SIZE). please guide me

Comment: Are you actually talking about a selected row or the current row, because they are two different things? A selected row is highlighted in the grid and is included in the `SelectedRows` collection. The current row is the row containing the cell that contains the caret and is accessed via the `CurrentRow` property. The current row may be selected or it may not. If you're talking about selection then how or even if the grid is bound is irrelevant, because it's specifically a UI matter. If you're talking about the current row then you absolutely should be using a `BindingSource`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your reply, right what you mean `SelectedRows` and `CurrentRow` but I don't use `BindingSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We thank them both for providing the best solution for us

In accordance with the solution from @RezaAghaei
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776898/datagridview-preserve-selected-index-and-scroll-position-after-update-and-reload)!

and In accordance with the solution from @R.Akhlaghi
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713311/maintaining-selected-row-of-the-datagridview-control-after-refreshing-data)!

I tried the code combination from them finally got a solution .

```
    Private pk1 As String
    Private pk2 As String
    Private pk3 As String
    Private pk4 As String
    Private rowIndex, scrollIndex As Integer
    Private IsSelectedRow As Boolean
  Private Sub Btnrefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnrefresh.Click
        Dim currentIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        pk1 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
                pk2 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
                pk3 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
                pk4 = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
                scrollIndex = DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
        IsSelectedRow = True
        population()
        Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(currentIndex).Cells(0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
        If IsSelectedRow Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Equals(pk1.ToString()) AndAlso row.Cells(1).Value.ToString().Equals(pk2.ToString()) AndAlso row.Cells(2).Value.ToString().Equals(pk3.ToString()) AndAlso row.Cells(3).Value.ToString().Equals(pk4.ToString()) Then
                    rowIndex = row.Index
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next row
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Selected = True
        End If
    End Sub
```